# Opened Port on Windows Server 2016 still not listening

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-firewall

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  I have a home server that I host SQL Server on.  I am trying to connect my app to the DB server (MS Sql Server).

I have opened ports 1433 and 1434 on the server through the Windows Firewall (inbound).

When I attempt to telnet in; it does not connect.

On the server - if I run netstat -a ---> I don't see 1433/1434 showing up in the list on listening ports.

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding port number 1433 or 1434 via SQL Server Configuration Manager ?

[image]

addl info :

https://devjef.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/on-which-port-is-sql-server-running/

Answer (score 0):

If Server is UP and you can connect via SSMS (from server) try this to find out which port server is listening to

```
SELECT local_tcp_port
FROM   sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE  session_id = @@SPID
GO

EXEC xp_ReadErrorLog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on', N'any', NULL, NULL, 'DESC'
GO


SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')
```

Comment: local_tcp_port is null.  But that still does not address the fact that i cannot telnet into the port